# import apns certyfikace from key vault using arm

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-notificationhub

I have arm which creates me notification hub namespace and the hub itself.
I also imported certificate into azure key-vault. 
Is it possible to use this certificate in arm or after deploying arm ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use key vault secrets in ARM templates, but you can only do so in two ways. Key vault secrets are referenced like this in ARM templates:

```
"sslCertData": {
  "reference": {
    "keyVault": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<vault-name>"
    },
  "secretName": "[parameters('keyVaultSslCertDataSecretName')]"
  }
}
```

However, you can only use this reference in the `parameters.json` file.

The first method of using the key vault involves creating a template with a parameter for the secret data:

```
"sslCertData": {
  "type": "securestring"
}
```

Then creating a `parameters.json` file containing the above key vault and secret name reference, and deploying the template with the parameters file from the command line:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
  -TemplateUri <The Template File URI> `
  -TemplateParameterFile <The Parameter File>
```

The second way is to use a parent or "wrapper" template that deploys a child template where you want to use the secret.

In the parent template, you would deploy this resource:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "name": "childTemplate",
  "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
  "properties": {
    "mode": "incremental",
    "templateLink": {
    "uri": "[variables('child-template-url')]",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "sslCertData": {
        "reference": {
          "keyVault": {
            "id": "[resourceId(parameters('keyVaultSubscriptionId'),  parameters('keyVaultResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('keyVaultName'))]"
          },
          "secretName": "[parameters('keyVaultSslCertDataSecretName')]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The parameters being passed into the child template are used to construct a parameters file. So just like in the first method, we're using a template file and a parameters file to be able to access the key vault secrets, but we can deploy this from the portal instead of the command line.

Comment: Great , thanks i forgot to mention I need this to upload apns for apple, do you know how to do it ?

Comment: I've never worked with Apple APNs before, so I can't help with that. You may need to post another SO question :)

Comment: could you take a look on that ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58130771/how-to-bind-key-vault-certificate-to-apns-notification-hub