# how to bind key vault certificate to apns notification hub

Tags: apple-push-notifications, key-value, azure-resource-manager, azure-notificationhub

I've got arm that creates notification hub instance
I imported certificate with password into key vault, and now I want to use that certificate as apns of notification hub for apple.

I am trying something like this but always get bad request:

```
  "type": "Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/notificationHubs",
  "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('namespaces_nhn_ecosystem_name'), '/nh-ecosystem-', parameters('environmentSuffix'))]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces', parameters('namespaces_nhn_ecosystem_name'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "authorizationRules": [],
    "apnsCredential": {
      "properties": {
        "apnsCertificate": "apns-cert-secret", <-name of the certificate in key vault 
        "certificateKey": "certpasswordhere",
        "endpoint": "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the whole template?

Comment: BUMP. it would be nice to be able to do this. Trying to do a similar thing in bicep with a apns cert stored in keyvault.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Notification Hubs does not support pulling PNS credentials from KeyVault (today). Customers have asked for this, and it's on the roadmap, but not supported today.